# ServiceStack Redis retry timeout exception

Tags: .net, exception, redis, servicestack-redis

I'm using `ServiceStack.Redis` in my application, I have a get method that goes to redis (cache) to get some information, but if redis is disconnected, I call the repository to get from the real database

```cs
try
    {
    IEnumerable<GetOrdensByIdQueryDTO> orders = await _redis.GetByHashId<GetOrdensByIdQueryDTO>(request.Account);
    if (orders == null || !orders.Any())
        return orders.OrderByDescending(order => order.UpdatedAt);
    return await GetFromWriteDataBase(request.Account);
    }
catch (Exception)
{
    return await GetFromWriteDataBase(request.Account);
}
```

If the redis is disconnected and I call the `_redis.GetByHashId()` method, it will throw an exception after 10 seconds, I need to remove this retry exception timer, and throw right before I call it, how can I do that?

I'm injecting Redis like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IRedisClientsManager>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var cacheConfiguration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CacheConfiguration>();

            return new RedisManagerPool(cacheConfiguration.ConnectionString);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the [AutoRetry Timeout](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#automatic-retries) with:

```
RedisConfig.DefaultRetryTimeout = 10000;
```

Comment: thanks man, i saw this but I was in doubt where to put this line, but i found it now, thanks :D